# Avoid code TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas

I've written a program to scrape data from Yahoo Finance and calculate some financial KPIs:

I get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` when I run the following code:

`Current_assets = BS_transpose['Current Assets'].str.replace(',','').astype(int)`.

I really don't understand why, can you just try to run it your side and see what's wrong with it? It seems that the problem comes from the line current assets bottom part of the program, but I don't understand why

Comment: you shoud look into yfinance lib: https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance, which download data from yahoo finance.

Comment: but I want to understand what wrong with this one, cause it gets information from Yahoo, only when I assign the current asset variable, it shows that Nonetype Error, and I want to understand why so I can manage it next time. If you can help me out with this it will be cool :)

Comment: because BS_transpose is None; get_table() doe does not return a value.

Comment: Many thanks ABC, the situation is fixed and the code is running well!!!

Answer (score 0):

BS_transpose is None. get_table() does not return a value.

So you can do either:

```
...
def get_table(url):
    ...
    ... 
    return df 
...
```

or

```
... 
# Balancesheet analysis 
BS_analysis = pd.read_csv('Last_Hope.csv')
# BS_analysis = pd.DataFrame(BS_transpose) #copy columns of dataframe
BS_analysis
...
```